# How to compare two types of classes which receives generics?

Tags: c#, generics, compare

I am trying to see if an object is of a specified type, but that type receives a generic, and I don't know how to do this check. For example let's say I have a class:

```
public class MyClass<T> where T : class
{
    private T Prop { get; set; }
}
```

and an empty class:

```
public class A : Object
{
}
```

Instantiating an object of `MyClass` with given type of `A` and comparing this object type to `MyClass` but which receives a type of `Object` will always return false, like in the following case:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new MyClass<A>();
        bool result = test is MyClass<Object>;
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here the type of `A` is `Object`, but the result will be always false.

In this case I just want to check if the object `test` has the type of `MyClass`, whatever `T` will be. How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: The type of `A` is *not* `object`. `MyClass<A>` and `MyClass<Object>` are two completely different types.

Comment: `var type = test.GetType();  bool result = type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyClass<>);`

Comment: try this `test is MyClass<>;`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: does not compile.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl thank you! Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Glad to help! nah, there's already an answer in the linked post, see Nathan's answer (..or Gabe's or .. just not the accepted one :) it sometimes happens that the accepted one is actually not the best one)

Comment: @quetzalcoatl , shoud I reopen the question if I need to compare a class which receives 2 generics? The code in that answer does not compile in this case

Comment: Just guessing - for 2+ generic parameters, it's `typeof(MyClass<,,,,,>)` - with as many commas as needed to mark all generic params - does that solve it? If so, then no, please leave it as it is. But if it's some other problem, then I'd say you should create another question about the new problem

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Great! Thank you!